# Setting a template variable inside a component used many times within a form for validation

Tags: angular

I have a form for a booking process, in that form there are different sections for adult/pensioner/children/infants, they all share the same 4 inputs but also have some unique ones depending on type. The duplicate sections have been split into a component which is then referenced in the form

Example:

```
form
  div adults
    common-input-component
    input #customerCode
  div
  div infants
    common-input-component
    input #dateOfBirth
  div
form
```

(Inside common-input-component.component.html)

```
input #firstName
input #lastName
```

All of the input fields have input validation and template variables are needed for divs for styling and visual feedback. This works perfectly because the component creates a unique scope for the template variables so they all are unique

When the user submits the form I want to set all of the elements to touched so that the validation divs are fired off, the problem is that because some elements are inside the common form component they are not added to the form validation. I looked around to solve this and found that adding this decorater fixed that issue: `viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }]` so now all validation is touched when the form is submitted and the page doesn't proceed if the form is invalid

The problem is that this ruins the scope of the component, meaning that the template variables are not unique so any time any #firstName ngModel is changed the validation result gets applied to all other inputs with #firstName because the scope is no longer closed to just the common-input component

I'm looking for suggestions on how to have both at the same time, have validation inside the child component affect the form but also have those template variables be unique

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was to put a name attribute on the inner components inputs

```
form
  div adults
    common-input-component [type]="'adult'"
    input #customerCode
  div
  div infants
    common-input-component [type]="'infant'"
    input #dateOfBirth
  div
form
```

(Inside common-input-component.component.html)

```
input #firstName name="{{type}}FirstName"
input #lastName name="{{type}}lastName"
```